# mysql Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database ''

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current code in config.php:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","roof") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("tarclibrary") or die(mysql_error());
```

this is my current code in register.php:

```
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

//Perform the verification of the nation
$email1 =$_POST['email1'];
$email2 =$_POST['email2'];
$pass1 =$_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 =$_POST['pass2'];

if($email1 == $email2){
    if($pass1 == $pass2){
        //All good.carry on

        $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
        $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass1);
        $pass2 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass2);
        $email1 = mysql_real_escape_string($email1); 
        $email2 = mysql_real_escape_string($email2);

        $pass1= md5($pass1);

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'uname' = '$uname'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            echo "Sorry, that user already exits";
            exit();
        }

        mysql_select_db('library') or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, uname, pass, email) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$uname'. '$pass1', '$email1')") or die (mysql_error());


    }else{
        echo "sorry,your passwords do not match.<br/>";
        exit();
    }
}else{
    echo "sorry your email's do not match<br/><br/>";
}
}else{

$form = <<<EOT

<h1><center>Register</center></h1>
<br>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<table class="t1" align="center" width="600" height="400">
<tr>
   <th scope="row">First name</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="fname" required type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Last name</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="lname" required type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Username</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="uname" required type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Password</th>
   <td><input type="password" name="pass1" required type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Confirm Password</th>
   <td><input type="password" name="pass2" required type="text"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
   <th scope="row">Email</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="email1" required type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Confirm Email</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="email2" required type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="register" type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"/>
</form>

EOT;

echo $form;

}
```

when I submit my register the output is:

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'library'

someone help pls , why is this happened??

Comment: Your password or user is wrong. Maybee you mean `root` and not `roof`?

Comment: update > mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: If the typing mistake is the problem, this question itself is not eligible to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to connect with following

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root", '') or die(mysql_error())
```

> MYSQL is Deprecated So please use mysqli

Comment: Try to use mysqli_connect() since mysql_connect() is deprecated in updated php versions.

Comment: lol, he asked in mysql and you replied in mysqli

Comment: I am suggesting to migrate. Not replying as an answer man.

Comment: Thanks @SanjayKumarNS I have change ans

Comment: Please don't answer low-quality questions, you will only encourage more low-quality questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following using `mysqli`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db_name");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die(mysql_error());
//replace third param with your actual password
```

mysql_connect is deprecated.. or use

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tarclibrary");
// To Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Comment: if there is no password just left empty remain quate ?after installed xampp haven't setup any setting yet and the syntax that you suggested is correct it in register.php or config.php ??

Comment: yes if password is empty then you mention it as "" ,and better you make connection in config

Comment: tried with first suggestion output = Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tarclibrary\register.php on line 92
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. '08f8e0260c64418510cefb2b06eee5cd', 'bbb')' at line 1

Comment: replace mysql_connect("localhost","root", "password") or die(mysql_error()); to suggestion 2 output = Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tarclibrary'

Comment: try with mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") and not mysql_connect("localhost","root", "password") because your password is empty as you said

Comment: yes , the code is <?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("tarclibrary") or die(mysql_error());

?> and output is Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tarclibrary\register.php on line 92
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. '08f8e0260c64418510cefb2b06eee5cd', 'bbb')' at line 1

Comment: and second change mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die(mysql_error()); to $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tarclibrary");
// To Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
become Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tarclibrary'

Answer (score 0):

You will connect to db as follows

```
     $link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","password");
     mysql_select_db('tarclibrary', $link);
     $sql = "INSERT into users values('', '$fname', '$lname', '$uname'. '$pass1', '$email1')";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: what is the '$company_name' means and the empty quate

Comment: this is my custom value you will insert your value.

Comment: add this to register or config.php ??

Comment: first two lines added in config.php and last two lines add in register

Comment: ok , is there i need to remove any current code ?like mysql_connect("localhost","root", '') or die(mysql_error()) or just insert this in

Comment: if you have the database password then put it at the place of passwrd. otherwise put the code as it is.

Comment: now my code for is config.php  $link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
     mysql_select_db('tarclibrary', $link);
  
mysql_select_db("tarclibrary") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: in register php i remove mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, uname, pass, email) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$uname'. '$pass1', '$email1')") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: and replace with $sql = "INSERT into users values('id', '$fname', '$lname', '$uname'. '$pass1', '$email1')";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);

Comment: when click register go to a blank pages it's succeed ? but in  myadminphp ,database taclibrary users table no any browse record created.

Comment: you just put the first two line in config.php and last two line in register as it is.

Comment: without remove my code and put the code that you mentioned , after click register result is Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tarclibrary\register.php on line 92
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. 'eab71244afb687f16d8c4f5ee9d6ef0e', 'nn')' at line 1

Comment: firstly remove your code for database connection and insert query.

Comment: how to ? what mean ? i'am beginer in php

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost","roof") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("tarclibrary") or die(mysql_error());

Replace above two line with my first two line. And

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, uname, pass, email) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$uname'. '$pass1', '$email1')") or die (mysql_error());

the above line with my last two line

Comment: and remove mysql_select_db('library') or die(mysql_error()); from register page.

Comment: ok, done now still have Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tarclibrary\register.php on line 92

Comment: problem is in your 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'uname' = '$uname'");

query.

Comment: what problem in here ? which syntax wrong ?

Comment: mysql_num_rows change to  mysql_query ??

Comment: mysql_query() or die(mysql_error()); to find the problem.

Comment: code now is $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'uname' = '$uname'")or die(mysql_error());
   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    echo "Sorry, that user already exits";
    exit();
   }

Comment: output becomes You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' WHERE 'uname' = 'nn'' at line 1

Comment: Try This
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname'");

Comment: i add pass = pass1 Now code is $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$pass1'") or die(mysql_error());
   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    echo "Sorry, that user already exits";
    exit();
   }

Comment: after refresh blank page out

Comment: in myadminphp database tarclibrary and go to users table no query result created

Comment: no error after submit come out a blank page . what does this mean , succeed?

Comment: check your table if data will be inserted then ok.

Comment: Downvoted for 2 reasons: 1) This code is terrible (No error checking/handling, building SQL queries by string concatenation, etc) and it will also not work in PHP 7+. 2) Answering low-quality questions will only encourage more low-quality questions