# getConnection not connection in JDBC on connecting with local mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, connection

I am trying to establish a connection with mysql db running on my machine.
    Here is the code -

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SecureSharedStore";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "password";

public static void main(String[] args) {
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try{
  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  //STEP 3: Open a connection
  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
 } catch(SQLException se){
  //Handle errors for JDBC
  se.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run this expect to connect to the local db but it gives an error saying the following -

Connecting to database.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.2.15' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:22)
```

When I see the first line I expect it to connect to 'root'@'localhost' but it is taking an IP address, that too not 127.0.0.1

Can you please help me on what I am missing. Pretty new to jdbc and using it specially on linux machines.

Stuck for too long on to it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that "localhost" actually resolves to 127.0.0.1?  (I have seen people do silly things with the "/etc/hosts" file that would break that assumption.)

Comment: @StephenC Using some else's VM image. So that could have been a possibility.
Found this in that file - (Can localhost2 cause some problem?)
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 localhost2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: Possibly related (though not Java): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796955/mysql-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database/.

Comment: I opened up the database for a particular user from all the locations instead of just localhost.
Its working but I was wondering how I could actually resolve the problem.
@StephenC - Looked into my.cnf of my mysql and its binding with the second ip address. That I understand is an issue. So I tried writing to that hostname when establishing connection but that too failed. 

For now, I have opened that user from everywhere but will see into this issue later. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first try to use localhost address as 127.0.0.1 and make sure your server is started.

Then check for DB credentials: are you sure about your username & pass?

Hope that'll help

Comment: Yes sure about credentials. It seems to be an issue of hostname, will look into it later. For now I have allowed that user from all locations and accessing the database.